# Run function in tmux within bash script

Tags: bash, tmux

My bash script has some functions and i need one tmux pane to execute function within bash script.
For example below code won't work and will be reported that command "internal" not found.

```
common() {
internal() {
echo "Function executed"
}   

SESSIONNAME="ses"

tmux new-session -s $SESSIONNAME -n session -d
tmux split-window -t $SESSIONNAME:0 -h

tmux send-keys 'internal' 'C-m'
tmux select-window -t $SESSIONNAME:0
tmux attach -t $SESSIONNAME
}
```

So how may i tell tmux to execute function from script where tmux pane was invoked ?

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a bash function that takes a function as an argument and loads it into a tmux session using 'send-keys'. Obviously the receiving tmux pane needs to be running bash or something compatible when this function runs.

```
_pass_to_tmux() {
    _FUNC_TO_PASS="${1}"
    _IFS_BACKUP="${IFS}"
    IFS=$'\n'
    for i in $(type ${_FUNC_TO_PASS} | tail -n +2); do
        tmux send-keys "${i}" C-m
    done 
    IFS="${_IFS_BACKUP}"
}
```

Comment: If you have a function that has lines ending with `;` (which is superfluous), that method may break. I've had good results with adding a `| sed "s/; *$//"` after the `tail -n +2`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not export shell functions to a tmux instance. At least in the 1.9 version of the tmux man page there is no reference to it.

I do not think this is possible at all since the context of the script where you are creating the tmux session is entirely different from the context within the tmux session. Thus it is not even able to have knowledge of these functions. Also, tmux might even use a different shell than the one you are using.

However, to provide some alternatives, what you can do is one of:

1. Write another script, put your `internal` function in it and use that instead.
2. Write a **library** script containing all your functions but nothing else, `source` that library script in **application** scripts so it's functions become available there and use these application scripts instead.

The second alternative also gives you more code hygiene and better reusability.